# Line feed problems with ZPL QR Code on Zebra Printer

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I'm having some issues with the using line feeds / carriage returns in ZPL with my Zebra LP2844z in CUPS (Raspberry pi).

According to Zebra's documentation and example, I just need to enable hex command using the FH switch, and use the hex encoded "_OD_0A" for a carriage return.

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/including-carraige-return-line-feed-in-qr-barcode-using-zpl.html

This example works fine until I try and add more lines:

```
^XA
^FO100,100
^BQN,2,10
^FH
^FDMM,B0024First Line _0D_0A Second Line _0D_0A Third Line _0D_0A Fourth Line _0D_0A ^FS
^XZ
```

This results in the following generated QR code:
[image: QR Code]

And contains the following text:

```
 First Line 
 Second LinTHIRD LINE UFOURTH LINE U
```

Something was going wrong at what appeared to be around the 24th byte which I realised coincides with the bytes "represented" (as mentioned in the documentation).

I then increased this further and found that I need to change the bytes representation in the "FDMM,B0nnn" switch for every byte in the string.   If I increase it over what appears to be an arbitrary number (let's say 100 bytes) it messes up the QR code text again.

That might work for static text where I know the length of the string in bytes.  However, I want to create these barcodes dynamically and each string will have a different byte length.

How can I handle it?

Comment: I think that this article should provide you some answers: https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/general/B_Switch_to_Add_Special_Characters_QR_BarCode.pdf

Comment: Thank you, so from what I can gather, I need a function  to count the bytes in the dynamically changing string and then set the value byte value from that before generating the qr code.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. This is what I have done:

^XA^MUM
^FT50,50^BQN,2,1^FH_^FDMM,AFirst Line,B0002_0d_0a,ASecond Line,B0002_0d_0a,AThird Line,B0002_0d_0a,AAll the lines that you need^FS
^MUM^XZ

This is the document that I have used to know what I need to do:
https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/general/B_Switch_to_Add_Special_Characters_QR_BarCode.pdf

I hope it will be helpful for you also.